# Need regular expression for removing operators and special characters

Tags: php, regex

I need regular expression for following,

```
H7X*4C9
H7X=4C9
H7X-4C9
H7X#4C9
```

Need to change above one into (need to remove special characters),
`H7X4C9`

except `H7X+4C9` (need to escape + alone in regex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using character classes?

```
$string = array('H7X*4C9', 'H7X=4C9', 'H7X-4C9', 'H7X#4C9', 'H7X+4C9');

foreach($string as $str) {
    echo preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9+]/i", '', $str) . "\n";
}
```

Explanations:

`[]` marks the character classes / list (i.e. what characters are allowed / not allowed)

`^` inside `[]` tells the engine to make the characters not allowed

`i` after the closing `/` tells the engine to ignore capitalization

http://codepad.org/U63JBdl0

Comment: You'd better to move the `+` sign outside the character class.

Comment: @M42 the requirement is to allow +. That's why it's inside the character class.